# Are there Rust variable naming conventions for things like Option<T>?

Tags: variables, rust, convention

Is there a convention for variable naming in cases like the following? I find myself having to have two names, one the optional and one for the unwrapped.

```
let user = match optional_user {
    Some(u) => {
        u
    }
    None => {
        new("guest", "guest").unwrap()
    }
};
```

Comment: One rule is that small scopes get short names, large scopes get long names.  In `Some(u) => u`, the scope is *extremely small* so using a long name is just noise, and `u` is a great choice.  But if it were `Some(u) => {...pages and pages of code...}`, I would probably use a name longer than `u`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure if there is a convention per say, but I often see (and use) `maybe` for `Option`s. i.e.

```
let maybe_thing: Option<Thing> = ...
let thing: Thing = ...
```

Also, in regards to your use of `u` and `user` in this situation, it is fine to use `user` in both places. i.e.

```
let user = match maybe_user {
    Some(user) => user,
    ...
```

This is because the match expression will be evaluated prior to the `let` assignment.

However (slightly off topic) @Manishearth is correct, in this case it would be nicer to use `or_else`. i.e.

```
let user = maybe_user.or_else(|| new("guest", "guest")).unwrap();
```

I'd recommend becoming familiar with the rest of [`Option`'s methods](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) too as they are excellent for reducing `match` boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use a variable to initialize another and you don't need to use the first variable anymore, you can use the same name for both variables.

```
let user = /* something that returns Option<?> */;
let user = match user {
    Some(u) => {
        u
    }
    None => {
        new("guest", "guest").unwrap()
    }
};
```

In the initializer for the second `let` binding, the identifier `user` resolves to the first `user` variable, rather than the one being defined, because that one is not initialized yet. Variables defined in a `let` statement only enter the scope *after* the whole `let` statement. The second `user` variable shadows the first `user` variable for the rest of the block, though.

You can also use this trick to turn a mutable variable into an immutable variable:

```
let mut m = HashMap::new();

/* fill m */

let m = m; // freeze m
```

Here, the second `let` doesn't have the `mut` keyword, so `m` is no longer mutable. Since it's also shadowing `m`, you no longer have mutable access to `m` (though you can still add a `let mut` later on to make it mutable again).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `match` block can be replaced by `optional_user.or_else(|| new("guest", "guest")).unwrap()`

Usually for destructures where the destructured variable isn't used in a large block, a short name like `u` is common. However it would be better to call it `user` if the block was larger with many statements.

Comment: `unwrap_or` would not be equivalent—it would see `new("guest", "guest")` evaluated eagerly rather than lazily. `optional_user.or_else(|| new("guest", "guest")).unwrap()` or `optional_user.unwrap_or_else(|| new("guest", "guest").unwrap())` would be equivalent.